# mount point i ubuntu10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

can any please tell me what is a mount point and why it is required in the installation process of ubuntu10.04.

Comment: sir thank u for u quick response but sir am still unable to find the correct use of mount point.

Answer (score 0):

A mount point is the equivalent of a 'drive letter' in Windows. Ubuntu maintains a single directory structure, with no drive letters. The concept of mounting is to have access to the files on a disk device in a specific directory, i.e. the mount point.

For example, `/dev/sdb1` is a block device file corresponding to the entire first partition of a disk. To mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Once this is done, the files on that partition will appear under the `/mnt` directory.

Comment: Happy to help. ;)